# jquery extend for i18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

I have a single page app. I use RequireJS, BackboneJS, etc and have the following code in my main.js

```
var myapp = {
    "i18n": {
        "myTranslationFile": "my-translations"
    }
};
```

Also inside main.js, I do

```
require([
    'app',
    // i18n utility
    'util/i18n'
    ], function(app, i18n){        
            myapp.i18n = $.extend(true, {}, i18n, myapp.i18n);
});
```

Just to add, the i18n.js looks like below;

```
define({
    "lang": function( key, valArr ){
        var str = this._translated_strings[key] || key;
        return str;
    },

    "setLang": function( obj ){
        this._translated_strings = $.extend(true, {}, obj);
    },

    "load": function(){
        var self = this,
            rootDeferred = new $.Deferred(),
            i18nDeferred = new $.Deferred();

        require([
            // Root translations
            // Active translations
        ],
        function(root, active){
            //rootDeferred.resolve();
        });

        rootDeferred.done(function(root, activeLang){

            var lang = $("html").attr("lang"),
                finalTranslations = {};

            if (
                typeof lang !== "undefined" && 
                typeof activeLang[lang] !== "undefined" && 
                activeLang[lang] === true
            ) {
                require(['resources/i18n/' + lang + '/' + self.myTranslationFile],
                    function(translations){
                        self.setLang(finalTranslations);
                    });
            } else {
                self.setLang(finalTranslations);
            }
        });

        return i18nDeferred;
    }
});
```

Now in my view, I use the following code to substitute the key with the string define inside my translation file;

```
myapp.i18n.lang("myKeyForString")
```

I am unable to understand how does this work? 
I mean I can see myapp.i18n clearly

but where does myapp.i18n.lang come from ?
Is that something to do with the jquery extend ?

Comment: You are extending `myapp.i18n` with this code `myapp.i18n = $.extend(true, {}, i18n, myapp.i18n);`.

Comment: From the specs: 'extends merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.' - the define method in i18n.js contains an object which then extends your myapp.i18n object. Therefore you can use myapp.i18n.lang, myapp.i18n.setlang and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code it goes like this:

1. Defining the **myapp** object inside *main.js*, containing some predefined key/value pairs.
2. The **require** method inside *main.js* says: As soon as you have loaded **app** and **utils/i18n** run the following function with **app** and **118n** objects as parameters. As mentioned in the comment above: jQuery `extend` merges the contents of two or more objects together into the first object. Your parameters in detail are: 
   `myapp.i18n = $.extend(true, {}, i18n, myapp.i18n);`

   - **true** - The merge becomes recursive (aka. deep copy).
   - **{}** - The target, the object to extend. It will receive the new properties.
   - **i18n** - The object containing additional properties to merge in (function parameter)
   - **myapp.i18n** - Additional objects containing properties to merge in (original object)

   The result: **myapp.i18n** now contains the old static key/values as well as the methods coming from **i18n**.
3. In *i18n.js* the requirejs **define** method sets up an object containing various methods. One of them is the **load** method which initializes the require i18n plugin. The function contains another require, retrieving all translation files. **Load** returns a jQuery deferred object. Such an object can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function. In short, it fills another object by using jQuery extend as soon as all translation files are loaded.

This is the way, how you can use **mapp.i18n.lang** as a function inside your view.